# jQuery/Sizzle to select Text nodes only (or, how to transform XPath expression to Sizzle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, sizzle

I have the following XPath expression to get all `textNodes` within a element.

```
var textnodes = document.evaluate('descendant::text()', element, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
```

Which works flawlessly across Chrome and Firefox, but IE.

Since Sizzle is browser-proof, I wanted to know, is there a way to select textNodes only with Sizzle/jQuery? As we all know, IE is a big deal, and there is no XPath for IE9 too (what about 10th?).

Or, in other words, how would I transform my XPath expression to Sizzle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, you can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType) to get the text nodes in an element using:

```
var textnodes = $('*').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
});
```

Comment: The result set doesn't match. `.contents().filter()` appears to be selecting only direct children of `element`, where XPath's `descendant::text()` looks recursively at all childs of `element`.  
P.S. Is http://api.jquery.com/ working for you? Appears to be down for me.

Comment: this should probably be `$(element).find('*').andSelf().contents()` etc

Comment: @thg435 nails it! At edited of @Joseph, that one loses the `element` context now.

Comment: @thg435 you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792910/is-there-an-alternative-to-jquery-sizzle-that-supports-textnodes-as-first-clas/13830980#13830980). It even allows you to filter the text nodes themselves without extra functions, as well as use `.end()`.